# Retrieve current date records from oracle database using vb6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have one table that contains a list of works. So I want to display the today's work list in msflexgrid using vb6.

code:

```
strwrlist = "Select * From BIOMED.HelpDesk_Work_Master where TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(WR_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MM:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MM:SS')='" & dt & "'"  
'dt hold the current date i.e. dt = Format(CDate(rsgetdt.Fields("SYSDATE")), "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")

MsgBox strwrlist
Set rsgetwrlist = Nothing

If rsgetwrlist.State = adStateOpen Then rsgetwrlist.Close

rsgetwrlist.Open strwrlist, Cn.con, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly 
Do While Not rsgetwrlist.EOF

    If IsNull(rsgetwrlist("WR_NO")) = False Then

        msflxgrdlow.TextMatrix(r, 0) = rsgetwrlist.Fields("WR_NO")

    End If
        msflxgrdlow.AddItem ""

    rsgetwrlist.MoveNext
    r = r + 1

loop
```

But it does not give me a list of records when I run this query from vb
and same query when I run in toad (oracle) it gives the list of work.
So what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

I expect part of it is you coersion between verious different formats for the date comparison.
Try just:

```
strwrlist = "Select * From BIOMED.HelpDesk_Work_Master where WR_DATE=TIMESTAMP'" & format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'"
```

making sure that both WR_DATE and the dt are properly Date typed (TIMESTAMP in Oracle).

This preserves and does the proper date conversion and comparison.

Comment: the tick will not be green unless it is clicked :)